# Unable to update component data from instance in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Since the introduction of Promise objects in Vue3, I am unable to update a component from its instance object (through `$refs`).

I need this so that I can just pass the component instance into a function and run some operations on it without having to manage bunch of variables in the parent component. This is a Quasar framework component, so I can not use store to update it from within.

Is there a workaround I could use to update a components values without doing so in the `<template>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use an application-level store, you avoid a lot of unnecessary headaches, and the readability of the application definitely improves.

you can use either https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/ or https://pinia.esm.dev/

another alternative is to use an event bus, with vue 3 it is better to use https://github.com/developit/mitt
but to use data across various components, it is always better to use the store

Comment: Problem is that I need to update a framework component, which I can not update through store.

Comment: it depends, you can watch in the component for a specific prop in the store, once you're in a component method you can do whatever you want

Comment: Yes but then I dont get the benefit of `"without having to manage bunch of variables"`.